# mysql 5.0 UPDATE syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have been trying to get this code to update, and it just will not work. I've been re-reading it and looking at other examples for hours and need some help to get this to work. It is a basic UPDATE script for a membership table in mysql database. I have mysql version 5.0.91. Nothing I have tried is working. When uploaded and tested in browser, returns echo "update query failed" I bolded the part where it is failing. I just can't find out why. When I check mysqladmin, the table is not updated.

```
$host="mysqlhost"; // Host name 
$username="mysqlusername"; // Mysql username 
$password="mysqlpassword"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mydbname"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="brothers"; // Table name 


// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");  

mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$mymname=$_POST['mymname'];
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 
$myconfirmpassword=$_POST['myconfirmpassword'];
$mysnumber=$_POST['mysnumber'];
$myemail=$_POST['myemail'];



if ($mypassword !== $myconfirmpassword) {
die ("passwords do not match. Try again!");




if (isset($_COOKIE['fname'])) {
$myfname = ($_COOKIE['fname']);
}

else {
die('could not find cookie fname'); 
}

if (isset($_COOKIE['lname'])) {
$mylname = ($_COOKIE['lname']);
}

else {
die('could not find cookie lname'); 
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE fname='$myfname' AND lname='$mylname'";
$result=mysql_query($sql)or die("no sql");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$fname=$row['fname'];
    if (!$fname) {
        die('variable not received');
        }
$lname=$row['lname'];
$position=$row['position'];
$committee=$row['committee'];}


if($mypassword==$myconfirmpassword) {

$query= "UPDATE brothers
SET `mname`='$mymname' WHERE `fname`    ='$fname'";

$chechresult= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 
if (!$checkresult) echo 'update query failed';


elseif ($checkresults) {
  echo'update query success';
setcookie('position', $position, time()+86400,'/');
setcookie('committee', $committee, time()+86400,'/');


$headsuccess=header( "location:done_registration.php");
$headsuccess;
if (!$headsuccess) {
    die('Could not redirect success registration'); }

}
}

else{
$headlogin=header( "location:error_registration.php");
$headlogin;
if (!$headlogin) {
    die('Could not redirect registration error'); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$chechresult= mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 
if (!$checkresult) echo 'update query failed';
```

you misspelled "k" with "h" in "$chechresult="

Comment: Thanks. I literally just found my error and was going to delete the question. But there's a learning experience for everyone else. Don't be an idiot like me and misspell your variable (*facepalm*)

Thanks for the help, everything works now.

Comment: @KyleRoseberry - in general, once a question is asked, don't delete it - especially if there are already answers. Someone may be editing their answer, or adding a new one, and it is _really_ annoying to go to all that effort, only to get an error message `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You've misspelled `$chechresult` - should be `$checkresult`; also, `$fname` should be `$myfname`!

It is probably worth echoing out `$query` to the screen, and trying that directly in your database - either on your console or in phpMyAdmin. Since `$fname` is empty (wrong var) your `WHERE` clause is wrong; at a guess it is affecting zero rows, and so is executing correctly.

Bear in mind that you have some SQL injection security issues in this code - make sure you escape your values before adding them to a query. Better yet, if you upgrade to PDO, you can use parameterisation, which will do the escaping for you.

Comment: How do I escape the code. I'm pretty new to this stuff. This is the first website I'm building from scratch. Could you give me an example of how to prevent sql injection?

Comment: Read all about the function you need, plus examples, [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to print $query string that contains the UPDATE order and after execute it in mysql console.

Comment: This should rather be a comment than an answer.